# Issues with reading from text file

Tags: c, readfile

I have been trying to read a text file in C and I have ran into issues. I had looked at a few tutorials and I found one that seems to work, however the outputted text contains lots of data that I don't need.

Here is my code:

```
int c;
FILE *file;
file = fopen(inputFilename, "r");
if (file) {
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

And here is an output:

```
The contents of testfile.txt file are:
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1344\cocoasubrtf720
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0 this is a test}
```

Obviously I'm just looking to output the 'this is a test' part.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since there are font names and colors, isn't that markup data from a text processor? If so, then you can't read only the text without some kind of parser for the format of the document. You would need a library that can do this, or do it yourself if you know the format of the document.

Comment: Ah, ok. The text was written in Text Edit.

Comment: Try using a pure text editor, like Notepad for Windows and Gedit for Linux. They don't add markup data to the file, just pure text.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I fixed the problem by changing the file to plain text from the format menu and it works absolutely fine now.